# Ubuntu 12.04 host – Virtualbox 4.1.12 Guest=Windows 7 – Network will not connect

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, virtualbox-networking

Ubuntu 12.04 host – Virtualbox 4.1.12 Guest=Windows 7 – Network will not connect.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on an Acer Aspire 5742-7645 laptop with 4GB memory, Intel Core i3 processor, Intel HD Graphics, DVD drive, 802.1 b/g/n, and 500 GB HD.
I connect to my router via a wireless connection.

I have installed Virutalbox 4.1.12 from the Ubuntu Software Center and installed Guest additions 4.1.12 in the Windows 7 guest session.

I have Windows XP and Windows 7 installed as guests in Virtual box
The network settings are different for XP and 7 – see below.
Network Settings
XP guest = Adapter 1:  PCnet-FAST III (NAT) -  Network works perfectly and has worked well for several years.

Network Settings
Win 7 = Adapter 1:  Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (Bridged adapter, eth1) 
Promiscuous Mode = allow all
Cable connected = checked

When I originally installed Windows 7, I tried NAT and the guest network would not connect.
Once I changed the setting to the above (Bridged) the Network worked perfectly.  However, what I believe  is after updates (not sure if it was an Ubuntu or Windows update) the guest network stopped working and I can not get it to connect.

Interfaces file content

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

Ifconfig yields
lou@lou-Aspire-5742:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:75:08:09:f6:5c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:0f:6e:7c:9f:01  
          inet addr:192.168.1.104  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4e0f:6eff:fe7c:9f01/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18095 errors:2 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:24344
          TX packets:9281 errors:47 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5301926 (5.3 MB)  TX bytes:1441885 (1.4 MB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:3208 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3208 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:294088 (294.0 KB)  TX bytes:294088 (294.0 KB)
```

Ipconfig yields the following:

Windows IP Configuration

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::38ba:dbca:a21d:c3d1%13
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.195.209
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{B292E440-679D-4FC5-8E34-77D6804669C8}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

I'm not sure what else to do. Can someone provide the troubleshooting steps to determine what the problem is and possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the kernel has been updated but the virtualbox drivers haven't been rebuilt. Try commands:

```
find /lib/modules | grep vboxnet
uname -a
```

To fix that use `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`